# Struggling to save an entity in OneToMany/ManyToOne relation using NestJS/TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Bookstore exercise. A `Book` can be assigned a single `Genre`
Trying to assign a new book with the `genreId` supplied in the DTO.

#### BookRepository

```
    @EntityRepository(Book)
    export class BookRepository extends Repository<Book> {
      constructor(
        private genreService: GenresService,
      ) {
        super();
      }

      async createBook(createBookDto: CreateBookDto): Promise<Book> {
        const genre = await this.genreService.getOne(createBookDto.genreId);
        const newBook = this.create({
          ...createBookDto,
          genre,
        });
        return newBook.save();
      }
    }
```

#### GenreService

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class GenresService {

      constructor(
        @InjectRepository(GenreRepository) private readonly genreRepository: GenreRepository,
      ) {}

      async getOne(id: number): Promise<Genre> {
        return this.getById(id);
      }

      private async getById(id: number): Promise<Genre> {
        const found = await this.genreRepository.findOne(id);

        if (!found) {
          throw new NotFoundException(`Genre with id ${id} not found.`);
        }

        return found;
      }
    }
```

BookRepository and GenreRepository are imported together by the `BookstoreModule`, like so:

```js
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
          GenreRepository,
          BookRepository,
          AuthorRepository,
        ]),
        // ...etc
    },
```

NestJS spits out the following error:

```
[ExceptionsHandler] this.genreService.getOne is not a function +1045981ms
TypeError: this.genreService.getOne is not a function
    at BookRepository.createBook (/Users/artur/Code/Sandbox/books-nest/dist/bookstore/books/book.repository.js:21:47)
    at BooksService.createBook (/Users/artur/Code/Sandbox/books-nest/dist/bookstore/books/books.service.js:29:36)
    at BooksController.create (/Users/artur/Code/Sandbox/books-nest/dist/bookstore/books/books.controller.js:31:33)
```

Tried to inject `GenreRepository into the`BookRepository`

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(GenreRepository) private genreRepository: GenreRepository,
){
    super();
}
```

and `.findOne()` from there, the error was:

```
No metadata for "2" was found. +26884ms
EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "2" was found.
```

(2 being the id for genreId)

Not sure if my approach to saving is correct. Maybe the idea of finding the genre from within BookRepository is wrong and it should be solved in a different way. If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the `createBook` method should be lying within the `BookService`, `BookService` needs to inject GenreService and then you should call the `genreService.getOne(createBookDto.genreId)` from within the `BookService`.
It makes more sense to let the services handle the business logic / orchestration of the data flow imo.

I'd suggest to give it a try try with the following code:

#### BookService

```js
@Injectable()
    export class BookService {

      constructor(
        @InjectRepository(BookRepository) private readonly bookRepository: BookRepository, 
private genreService: GenreService // <= here you go, you inject the genreService into the bookService to take advantage of its methods
      ) {}

      async getOne(id: number): Promise<Genre> {
        return this.getById(id);
      }

      async createBook(createBookDto: CreateBookDto): Promise<Book> {
        const genre = await this.genreService.getOne(createBookDto.genreId);
        const newBook = this.create({
          ...createBookDto,
          genre,
        });
        return newBook.save();
      }

      private async getById(id: number): Promise<Genre> {
        const found = await this.bookRepository.findOne(id);

        if (!found) {
          throw new NotFoundException(`Book with id ${id} not found.`);
        }

        return found;
      }
    }
```

#### BookRepository

```js
    @EntityRepository(Book)
    export class BookRepository extends Repository<Book> {}
```

#### GenresService

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class GenresService {
    
      constructor(
        @InjectRepository(GenreRepository) private readonly genreRepository: GenreRepository,
      ) {}
    
      async getOne(id: number): Promise<Genre> {
        return this.getById(id);
      }
    
      private async getById(id: number): Promise<Genre> {
        const found = await this.genreRepository.findOne(id);
    
        if (!found) {
          throw new NotFoundException(`Genre with id ${id} not found.`);
        }
    
        return found;
      }
    }
```

#### GenreRepository

```js
    @EntityRepository(Genre)
    export class GenreRepository extends Repository<Genre> {}
```

### Edit DTO comment

#### CreateBookDto

```js
    import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';
    import { IsNumber, IsString, IsDate } from 'class-validator';

    @Exclude()
    export class CreateBookDto {
        @Expose()
        @IsNumber()
        genreId: number;

        @Expose()
        @IsString()
        title: string;

        @Expose()
        @IsString()
        author: string;

        @Expose()
        @IsDate()
        date_of_publication: Date;

        // rest of informations....
    }
```

Note that we're using `class-transformer` along with `class-validator` in order to instantiate and validate a proper **CreateBookDto**. CreateBookDto can be instantiated at the controller level if you're using [validation pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#the-built-in-validationpipe)

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! That makes a perfect sense - in that struggle, somehow th architecture slipped my mind. Will let you know tomorrow if that works when I am back at the code.

Comment: Looks like you accepted my answer, glad to help ! ;)

Comment: Yes, definitely, thank you once again! I still have tons of uncertainty around relations, I have seen lot of different approaches, but I hope this will all settle down at some point :)

Comment: What should be the createBookDto look likes in this case? Should we add genre or not? I am struggling with DTO rest I understand the logic.

Comment: I've added an example of what createBookDto  could be in this case. Hope it's clearer